# Dynamics Online: Maximum Controls Limit Exceeded

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am customizing dynamics-crm-online system to my company and I am totally new to this. 
I create a dashboard which can take 8 charts components , but I get error message of maximum controls limit. How I can increase this limit ??
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change this limit for online-environments (if you were on-premises it would be possible by changing the [DashboardSettings.MaximumControlsLimit Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.deployment.dashboardsettings.maximumcontrolslimit?view=dynamics-deployment-ce-9)).

You could in theory iframe one dashboard inside another dashboard, but that is not a solution I would recommend: You simply have to prioritize what you show on your dashboards.

Comment: if I contact Microsoft , are they able to increase it ?

Comment: I highly doubt that they would do so (but it is not something I have tried).

Comment: @HenrikH - why do you think you cannot set this for online environment ? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4676c26b-8f5b-4497-b552-056e74ab2a07

Comment: Quoting Gustaf Westerlund: _you can only do this change in a CRM onprem environment where you are the deployment admin_ http://gustafwesterlund.blogspot.com/2016/10/extending-max-amount-of-components-on.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using Powershell.
Take a look at the following link that provides the PowerShell source on how to implement this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334200.aspx#set_controls_limit

The maximum documented number should be 20.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the record limit in the database with statement

USE MSCRM_CONFIG

GO

select ColumnName,IntColumn from DeploymentProperties where ColumnName='AggregateQueryRecordLimit'

You can set this higher.

Do keep in mind that it is at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

There are two claims, you could take both of them as reference:

1. The maximum number is 6, and it could be increased to 20 by code.

A dashboard can contain charts, grids, IFRAMEs, or web resources. By default, a single dashboard can contain up to six of these components.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/customize-dev/understand-dashboards-dashboard-components-formxml#dashboard-components

You can change the number of components to be displayed on a dashboard using Windows PowerShell by setting DashboardSettings.MaximumControlsLimit property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg594397(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN (*)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.deployment.dashboardsettings.maximumcontrolslimit?view=dynamics-deployment-ce-9

(Confirmation is needed to claim 1, because the doc(*) stated that DashboardSettings.MaximumControlsLimit applies to Dynamics 365 (online),

however, from other answers in forum, it seems that the proerty only works in on-premise.)

2. The maximum number is based on user count. (Online environment)

https://cargas.com/blog/now-you-can-have-more-than-6-dashboard-components/